# Unable to access django admin panel in a django angular project

Tags: javascript, python, angularjs, django, django-rest-framework

I am using AngularJS for my front-end and Django with Django rest framework as back-end. I have used angular's ui-router to connect to backend via DRF's rest api. I want to access django's admin panel and DRF's browsable api in development environment. Should I create a route in angular to access it and put some permission's on the server side or is there a better way to achieve this?

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'accounts', AccountViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^api/v1/', include(router.urls)),
    url(r'^api/v1/auth/login', LoginView.as_view(), name='login'),
    url(r'^api/v1/auth/logout', LogoutView.as_view(), name='logout'),
    url('^.*$', IndexView.as_view(), name='index')
]
```

Comment: admin panel will be there in /admin anyway (i mean default)

Comment: @itzmeontv i am not able to access it. I think that it is because routing is being handled by angular's ui-router but i am not sure.

Comment: post your complete url you are trying to access admin

Comment: Most likely you've configured your URLs in Django in a wrong way. Could you post your url.py?

Comment: @itzmeontv I have added urls.py